# Intento mandar un mensaje donde no se encontró el registro con dicho código,utilizando empty query

Tags: php, android, mysql

**Este es mi código PHP** 
 Estoy trabajando  con Android   y mysql.
Alguien por favor  podría  ayudarme.

```
 <?php 
 require('conexion.php');
 define('MYSQL_ERROR_EMPTY_QUERY', '1065');
 try{
 $Code=$_GET['Code'];
 $sql="select * from tb_usuario WHERE Code=?";
 $stm=$conn->prepare($sql);
 $stm->execute(array($Code));
 $result=$stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $json=json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
 print_r($json);
 }
 catch(PDOException $e){
 if ($e->errorInfo[1] == MYSQL_ERROR_EMPTY_QUERY) {
      echo "No exite un  registro  con dicho  código! ";
    } 
    }
 ?>
```

**Esta es mi conexión a la  base de datos.**.
**Conexion.php**

```
      <?php
          mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
          mb_http_output('UTF-8');
          try{ 
             $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxxxx';
             $usuario = 'root'; 
             $password = 'xxxxxxx'; 
             $opciones = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',); 
             $conn = new PDO($dsn,$usuario,$password,$opciones);
             $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    

        }catch(PDOException $e){ 
             echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage(); 
       } 

      ?>
```

Comment: Intentaste mandar el mensaje y... ¿qué ocurrió? Te quedaste corta en el planteamiento del problema. Por lo demás, PDO tiene mejores métodos para saber si hubo o no resultado. Ejemplo evaluando la variable `$result` directamente: `if ($result){ hubo datos }else{ no hubo ...}`

Comment: @A.Cedano  Ya hice el  procedimiento  que me  indicas  y no me  corrió, por  tal motivo estoy  tratando  de  realizar la  consulta con  empty  query.  Espero  puedan  ayudarme. Saludos

Comment: 1º. No era necesaria una autorespuesta. Podías editar la misma pregunta y poner las dos formas del código. Eso puedes hacerlo dándole a **editar**, al final de la pregunta. 2º. Por favor indica qué es lo que no corre, si presenta algo en pantalla, si no presenta nada, si puedes ver algún mensaje relevante en el archivo errorlog, etc. Es posible que haya un problema a nivel de la conexión a la BD. ¿Puedes poner el código del archivo `conexion.php` borrando los datos sensibles tales como nombre de usuario, contraseña, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Probé tu código y el único error que encontré fue que yo tengo corriendo MySQL en otro puerto por lo que el único cambio que hice fue agregarle el puerto:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=XXXX;dbname=XXXX';
```

Puedes agregar el error para ver que esta pasando, podría ser un error en el query o como ya te mencionaron error a nivel de base de datos.